# MySQL Query error: Incorrect datetime value

Tags: mysql

I have a table that stores forum messages.  It has a column called date_modified that is pretty self-explanatory.  Whenever a user modifies a post, that column is updated to the current time for that row.  If a message has never been modified, it shouldn't have a value.  Now, whenever I try to modify the table, I get an error saying `Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'date_modified' at row 1`, even when the table modification is completely unrelated to that column.  Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE forum_messages
(
  message_id    INT(15) AUTO_INCREMENT
    PRIMARY KEY,
  author_id     INT(15)                             NOT NULL,
  thread_id     INT(15)                             NOT NULL,
  board_id      INT(15)                             NOT NULL,
  content       TEXT                                NOT NULL,
  date_posted   TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  modifier_id   INT(15)                             NOT NULL,
  date_modified TIMESTAMP                           NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: show a row of data and exactly what you are doing to try to modify it

Comment: try changing default value from current value you have to --> DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

Comment: What does the manual say about the timestamp data type?

Answer (score 0):

Make it NULL, a zero date and NULL date are not the same.

Comment: All modificiations are bringing up this error.  Even when I try to make it null.  I'd rather not delete the table and recreate it with that column already null.

Comment: It's likely the existing data relations causing the error. For the sake of time, you may as well recreate.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL documentation says

> The server requires that month and day values be valid, and not merely
>   in the range 1 to 12 and 1 to 31, respectively. With strict mode
>   disabled, invalid dates such as '2004-04-31' are converted to
>   '0000-00-00' and a warning is generated. With strict mode enabled,
>   invalid dates generate an error.

so maybe you trying to insert value with incorrect tymestamp format

Comment: Given that this is so thoroughly covered in the manual, I can't see the merit in repeating it here :-(

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me. I found a row with a value of 0000-00-00 for expiry_date which was a datetime column. I deleted this row and I can finally alter my table.